# How to hide TextView and Button without messing up layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button, textview and an EditText which are ordered accordingly in my RelativeLayout. I want to hide the button and textview but still maintain the position of the EditText. I tried doing android:visibility:gone but didn't seem to work. This is what I have:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title"
    android:background="@color/red" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/exit"      
    android:text="@string/name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="1" >
```

Pretty much I want justthe EditText to appear in its location without the textview and the button. Please help

Comment: do no use android:visibility="gone" rather use android:visibility="invisible". Because when you put something in relativelayout things are arrange in relation of each other's position. So when you say visibility GONE blank view is created with 0,0 width and height but when you say visibility INVISIBLE view is created and keep ocupied it size and position just not visible on screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `android:visibility="gone"` to `android:visibility="invisible"` to keep it's shape but make it invisible.

In code you can set

```
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Quick question, I am not in an environment to test right now, I was wondering if it is possible to put an onclicklistenenr on the button for example, even when it is set to invisible

Comment: yes. you can set a listener to a view, no matter of its visibility. even on views which are `GONE`.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering is there even a way to make the RelativeLayout height/width take into consider only the edittext.. Like if I put "wrap_content" for width/height in RelativeLayout, can I set it to wrap around the Edittext only?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

`android:visibility = "invisible"`

in this case. It will not effect your other views in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/name"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="1" >
</EditText>
```